# What does the exclamation mark in a visual studios project dependencies mean?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-project

In my Visual Studio solution, i have a project, where und 'Dependencies', a brownish (dark yellow?) exclamation mark symbol is shown. I cannot find any information regarding it's meaning. What does it mean? [image]

Comment: Looks like a generic "warning" symbol, indicating something wrong with the innermost dependency with the icon. The icons on the enclosing dependencies are likely just propagated from the inner one. Possibly, the innermost thing needs an update?

Comment: Visual Studio starts parsing your project immediately after it got loaded, in the background, helping to speed up subsequent operations like IntelliSense info.  It doesn't yell loudly when that parse fails, since it is in the background, other than by displaying these warning triangles.  Get the real problem, if any, by building the project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was just a transient problem. Building the project did not yield any warnings or errors. After restarting visual studio, the exclamation point was gone.